# Proof that given matrix form normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let G be the group of all nonsingular lower-triangular 2x2 matrixes (with non-zero determinant) with $\mathbb{R}$ coefs. Proof that all matrixes that are contained in $G$ and look like this: 
$\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
* & a^2 
\end{pmatrix}$
form a normal subgroup in G.

P.S I was trying to apply following lemma: for $H$ being subgroup of $G$ than $H$ may be called normal subgroup if and only if $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H\  \forall g \in G $. However it is hard form me to apply it here. Any solutions?

Comment: Maybe, it is easier to show $\ gH=Hg\ $ for every $\ g\in G\ $ ? This is another equivalent condition for a normal subgroup.

Comment: @Peter, will try that, thanks!

Comment: @освящение, don't understand what your comment states..

Comment: @9cloudalpha Does $\ast$ represent any real number?

Comment: @освящение, yeah. I don't even understand what should I do in my proof. Should I just take abstract lower-triangular matrix with non-zero determinant, multiply them left and right and show the equality, or what?)

Comment: @Peter, unfortunately that doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} 
\end{pmatrix}$ be in given $G$ such that  $\det A \neq 0$ and suppose $B=\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
* & a^2 
\end{pmatrix}$ is in the given subgroup $H$.

Now, try to show that $ABA^{-1}$ is of the  form  $\begin{pmatrix}
b & 0 \\
c & b^2 
\end{pmatrix}$, where all the coefficients are real.

Comment: Thanks, will try

Comment: just find the value of $b, c$.

Comment: That worked, however would that be enough?

Comment: To show a subgroup $H$ to be normal in a group $G$, we have a nice tool which says for all $h$ in H and for all $g$ in G, $ghg^{-1}$ should be in $H$. As I have taken arbitrary elements $A$ and $B$ in the answer, so it is enough to show $ABA^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: Got it, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You must show that for $$\begin{bmatrix}u&0\\v&w\end{bmatrix}\in G,\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\b&a^2\end{bmatrix}\in H$$ there exists $$\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\y&z\end{bmatrix}\in H$$such that$$\begin{bmatrix}u&0\\v&w\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\b&a^2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\y&z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u&0\\v&w\end{bmatrix}$$Writing out the equations for row 1, column 1; row 2,column 1; row 2, column 2, we have $$ua=xu,$$ $$va+wb=yu+zv$$ $$wa^2=zw$$, so $$x=a,z=a^2,$$
$$y=\frac{va+wb-a^2v}{u}$$ so $$\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\y&z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\\frac{va+wb-a^2v}{u}&a^2\end{bmatrix}\in H$$